# Receive Image with Java Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am receiving Images using Kafka Consumer. Here it is the snippet:

```
byte[][] message_send = new byte[size_array] [] ; //create matrix
       System.out.println("Starting Consuming");
       while ((dispatcher.AcceptedNumberJobs > 0)  || (dispatcher.queue_size > 0) ) {
           dispatcher.consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(Topic));
           System.out.println("Polling");
           ConsumerRecords<String,byte[]> records = dispatcher.consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
           int i = 0;
           for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
               dispatcher.AcceptedNumberJobs -= 1;
               dispatcher.queue_size -= 1;
               System.out.println(record.getClass());
               System.out.println(record.value().getClass());
               message_send[i]= java.util.Arrays.copyOf((byte[])record.value(), ((byte[])record.value()).length);
```

The consumer is create as follows:

```
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG , BootstrapServer);
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, ConsumerID);
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG , "earliest");
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
        KafkaConsumer<String , byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer <String , byte[]>(prop);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(Topic));
```

When I copy the record to message_send I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Could you help me in this?

---

Update:
I changed the consumer config with:

```
prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
```

However I get another weird behaviour, the first image is correctly received, the other elements in the array are null. Could you help me in this? Also, are there reference which are just not reference for apache kafka in Java?

So:

message_send[0] has a value, the other do not.

Comment: Your value deserializer is `String` but it should be `ByteArrayDeserializer`.

Comment: As I am new, can you please tell me where do you mean this?

Comment: Without testing, I believe this `prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());` should be changed to `prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());`.

Answer (score 0):

You've set `ConsumerRecords<String,byte[]>`

But that doesn't match `ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG`, which should instead be `ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName())`

Therefore, the error is saying String (from your consumer config) cannot be cast to a byte array (from your constructor and poll statement)

Comment: You don't need to make copies of anything, but sure, `new byte[size_array][]` makes `size_array` number of null entries within an array. If you don't want that, use a `List<byte[]>`... That has nothing to do with Kafka

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get this, I create an array of the specific size_array because I know that I want to consume precisely size_array messages of bytes. What is the problem with this and how would you handle this? Actually, I am thinking, is it possible that the result of a poll is an empty record?

Comment: Yes, poll result can be empty.... You should use `records.count()`, not `size_array`. Still, you could also use an arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the updated problem by just counting the record in records, as I understood that actually, a poll request can return also empty records. The problem was that I was appending to the array of empty elements and I thought it was a problem in consuming the messages.